# After Buttonclick delegation: (ViewController) has no segue with identifier 'pushToSecondStep'

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I'm really going crazy on this.
But let me explain to you my little project first:

I have an Custom `UITableView` `TDStartTableView`.
Also in there I have some methods implemented for rendering the table. No problem there.
Inside of one `TableViewCell` there is a button.
When that Button is clicked it triggers this method:

```
- (void)triggerPush {
    [self.delegate pushNextView];
}
```

`self.delegate` is specified in the .h file of `TDStartTableView` like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<TDStartTableViewDelegate> delegate;
```

Also, the reference is set in my `UITableViewController`:

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

**So essentially what I'm trying to do is: Create a custom `UITableView` with Buttons etc. and then listen on the events from a `ViewController` that is implementing that `UITableView` and the protocol**

So because the protocol forces me to implement `pushNextView` this method is in my UIViewController:

```
- (void)pushNextView {
    NSLog(@"This works");
}
```

**To this point everything works just fine, no problem there!**

But now comes the tricky part.

I create a segue from my `UIViewController` to a new ViewController. I connect them via a segue and name the segue appropriately. `pushToSecondStep`.
[image: I'm going crazy]

Now one would think, that when I change the implementation of `pushNextView` to this

```
- (void)pushNextView {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushToSecondStep" sender:self];
}
```

it works. But what I get is:

`'Receiver (<TDFirstStepTableViewController: 0x8dc97d0>) has no segue with identifier 'pushToSecondStep''`

Please help, I'm going crazy :D

Comment: Also i checked the memory address at initialization point and the one from the exception and they are both the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that I overwrote a constructor of `TDStartTableView`.

The proper form is that you implement all constructors, so that Objective-C can instantiate them all by itself:

```
- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

   self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

   return self;
}
```

Also when you implement a custom `UITableView` Widget you shouldn't use `UITableViewController` but `UIViewController`.

Also you don't initialize your custom `UITableView` yourself, Storyboard already does that for you, so if you want to set special variables for it like `numberOfRows` then just declare a property and then set it via a setter-method outside and call `[tableView reloadData]`.

Also, thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/1095089/shubhank for helping me in the chat :)